# unable to set password with the script

Tags: powershell

After some research I have found and adapted the script for my needs

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-csv c:\users\administrator\desktop\output.csv |

New-ADUser -path "ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxxxx,dc=xxx" -passthru |
ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Pa$$w0rd123" -Force) -PassThru
    $_ | Enable-ADAccount 
    }
```

I can create users with this script in OU but passwords seems to be not working. I have to reset it manually and set one by one.

What I'm doing wrong ? BTW, Server 2016

Comment: Try adding an `AccountPassword` property to the `Import-Csv` output with a calculated property rather than changing the password after user creation.

Comment: Apparently  PS doesn't like $$ in the password string. Have used different password and all sorted. Thanks Ansgar. Will try your advise as well

Comment: Ah, I didn't even look at the particular password you were setting. It's not that PowerShell wouldn't like `$$` in the password string, it's that `$$` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0), which, like all other variables, gets expanded in a double-quoted string. Always use single-quoted strings unless you have variables (or escape sequences) in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ marks a variable in powershell. Ypu need to escape the characters in order to put dollarsigns in to strings, like `set string="$"`. Put a 'grave' (`) before the character to escape it. You could also encase your string in single quotes, which will tell powershell not to expand variables.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a string variable, and it contains a $ will behave according to what method you used to cast the string.

Using double quotes "" will tell Powershell that yeah, this is text alright, but if I put a variable in here, it should output that variable in the text string.

If you wish to have a string and use $ and have Powershell not react on it, use single quotes ''.

This will make Powershell take the $ as just a character in the string and not a variable it tries to find and put into the string.